# iOS- Update UITableViewCell information without reloading the row?

Tags: ios, uitableview, key-value, key-value-observing

Let's say you have a `UITableView` that displays a list of `file` metadata, and you want to show the `download_progress` of each file in a `UILabel` of a custom `UITableViewCell`. (This is an arbitrarily long list - thus dynamic cells will be reused).

If you want to update the label without calling either `reloadData` or `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`, how can you do it?

For those who are wondering - I don't want to call either of the `reload...` methods because there's no need to reload the entire cell for each percentage point update on `download_progress`.

The only solutions I've come across are:

- Adding the cell as a key-value observer for the `file`'s `download_progress`.
- Calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath...` directly to obtain the label and change it's text.

However,
KVO in general isn't a fun api to work with - and even less so when you add cell reuse into the mix. Calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` directly each time a percentage point is added feels dirty though.

So, what are some possible solutions? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: would you need to show progress to the granularity of every percentage point? You could just monitor the progress, and only reload the cells every 25% or something?

Comment: That would be the fallback I suppose. The iOS podcast app actually does a good job of showing continuous progress without reloading the cells. I wonder how it's done...

Comment: you could also maybe try just relaying out just the subview tree of a custom subview within your cell that has the progress indicator?

Comment: By setting a flag then only updating the necessary subview after a call to `reload...`? The only issue is that the cell's height will be recalculated, and if the cell is currently being edited (i.e. showing the "delete" button on the right) then it will abruptly swipe the cell back to the right. I'd like to see if I could get away with not calling one of the `reloads`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a corollary to Doug's response, here is what I ended up going with:

Each `file` has a unique identifier, so I made it responsible for posting notifications about updates to its attributes (think KVO, but without the hassle):

I made a `FileNotificationType` enum (i.e. `FileNotificationTypeDownloadTriggered`, and `FileNotificationTypeDownloadProgress`). Then I would send the progress into the `NSNotification`'s `userInfo NSDictionary` along with the `FileNotificationType`.

```
- (void)postNotificationWithType:(FileNotificationType)type andAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes
{
    NSString *unique_notification_id = <FILE UNIQUE ID>;

    NSMutableDictionary *mutable_attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:attributes];
    [mutable_attributes setObject:@(type) forKey:@"type"];

    NSDictionary *user_info = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:mutable_attributes];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:unique_notification_id object:nil userInfo:user_info];
    });
}
```

The `file` object also has a method to enumerate what types of notifications it could send:

```
- (NSArray *)notificationIdentifiers
{
    NSString *progress_id = <FILE UNIQUE ID + FILENOTIFICATIONTYPE>;
    NSString *status_id = <FILE UNIQUE ID + FILENOTIFICATIONTYPE>
    NSString *triggered_id = <FILE UNIQUE ID + FILENOTIFICATIONTYPE>

    NSArray *identifiers = @[progress_id, status_id, triggered_id];
    return identifiers;
}
```

So when you update an attribute of a `file` elsewhere, simply do this:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{@"download_progress" : @(<PROGRESS_INTEGER>)};
[file_instance postNotificationWithType:FileNotificationTypeDownloadProgress andAttributes:attributes];
```

On the receiving end, my table view delegate implemented these methods to add / remove my custom `UITableViewCells` as observers for these notifications:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    File *file = [modelObject getFileAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    for (NSString *notification_id in file.notificationIdentifiers)
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:cell selector:@selector(receiveFileNotification:) name:notification_id object:nil];
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:cell];
}
```

Finally, the custom `UITableViewCell` has to implement the `receiveFileNotification:` method:

```
 - (void)receiveFileNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    FileNotificationType type = (FileNotificationType)[notification.userInfo[@"type"] integerValue];

    // Access updated property info with: [notification.userInfo valueForKey:@"<Your key here>"]

    switch (type)
    {
        case FileNotificationTypeDownloadProgress:
        {
            // Do something with the progress
            break;
        }
        case FileNotificationTypeDownloadStatus:
        {
            // Do something with the status
            break;
        }
        case FSEpisodeNotificationTypeDownloadTriggered:
        {
            // Do something if the download is triggered
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone who is looking to update tableview cells without having to reload them! The benefit over key-value observing is that you won't get issues if the `File` object is deallocated with the cell still observing. I also don't have to call `cellForRow...`.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I would create a custom cell, which I'm guessing you've done. Then I'd have the cell listen for a specific notification that your download progress method would post, then update the label there. You'd have to figure out a way for your download progress to specify a certain cell, maybe by a title string or something that would be unique that your download progress method could be told, so your cell update method could make sure the note was meant for it. Let me know if you need me to clarify my thought process on this.

Comment: Yeah I can try an NSNotification with the file's unique id as the name. Where in the cell's lifecycle were you thinking about adding / removing the cell as an observer? Add in `tableviewWillDisplayCell...` and remove in  `tableviewDidEndDisplayingCell...`?

Comment: I hadn't got that far, but your suggestion is probably a pretty good place to do it.